# During Google Sheets formula entry, want keyboard shortcut to select a whole column

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-sheets

In MS Excel, I can type the following formula

```
=SUM(A:A)
```

Without taking my hands off the keyboard. I start in cell B1, I type `=SUM(` then I use the cursor keys to move one cell to the left, hit CTRL-SPACE (which turns the A1 into A:A) then type `)`

Is there any way to get google spreadsheets to do the same thing? The CTRL-SPACE shortcut works for selecting cells, but not within a formula. Is there some other way to do what I'm after?

I *can* use CTRL-SHIFT-DOWN but the end result is a reference to the range `A1:A1000` - so if I subsequently add another 1000 rows to the spreadsheet, my formula doesn't extend.

Please help, my muscle memory is working against me right now... and the mouse is **so** far away!

Edit: Apologies, browser is chrome (but I'll use anything if I can get this to work). OS is Windows 10

Comment: @K7AAY - edited above, apologies

Comment: Always AOK; your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consulted the Google Sheets Help Forum, and the [expert advice from there](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/pC8UJw4jP8g;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/category$3A(spreadsheets)$20is$3Afirstpost%7Csort:date) confirms that feature does not exist yet. Instead, they suggested

> "If you'd like to influence future versions of Google Sheets, Feature
>   Requests are encouraged. You can submit your idea using the **HELP** >
>   **Report a Problem** menu. I know that those submissions are valued by the Sheets team."